# Problem with login feature

Tags: web-app

I am making an Training and Placement cell application which would be useful for our institutions but i am having problem with login feature.There are two user in my application admin and student and i have to make login with two different restrictions so how can i make?

Comment: What is the UX question? It sounds like an implementation question.

Comment: Once the user logs in, you'll know what role they have, right (i.e. you'll know if it's an admin or a student account)? Do you need to know this before they log in?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be two different types of login. Any user should login normally. Once a user logs in, the rights of the users if assigned as an Admin should be displayed preferably with a tag called 'Admin' somewhere near the username on the profile.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who the primary audience is:
The login for the primary audience would take the center stage and be shown on the login page when the application is accessed. 
You can create Tabbed Login box to facilitate both Student and Admin login and possibly add another functionality to save login information such that if the same user logs in using their device they would see the credentials entry view which pertains to them.